# Missing Controller CakePhp 3.4.9

Tags: php, cakephp

This is my first ever project with CakePHP, I am using version 3.4.9.
I have followed the naming conventions, but I am unable to access from URL http://localhost:8765/job_titles
As it should show me the table fields of table job_titles, instead it is giving me this error.

[image]

I have searched a lot and tried the solutions people have suggested, but this error won't go away.

I will be asking this same on cakePhp forum, so get mad if find it as a duplicate.

here is the file:
[image]

Comment: Did you try to do what it says in the big yellow bar? I.e. create a file `src\Controller\JobTitlesController.php` with a `class JobTitlesController`?

Comment: The file is already present in that directory. With all the coding. That is why I am unable to get the problem.

Comment: Can you post the code you have in that file? Specifically, the used namespace, classes imported via `use` and the declaration of your controller class.

Comment: I have Updated.

Comment: Is the file accessible by PHP (in terms of permissions)? Also what route class have you configured (for that route)?

Comment: I have not configured anything. I have installed the cakePHP with composer, created a project, created the database and assigned it to cakephp. Then I baked the table.

Comment: Note: I am using Xampp's Mysql.

Comment: In that case you're using the wrong URL, as the default route class is `DashedRoute` with expects you to use `job-titles` instead.

Comment: Oh my. Thank you ndm.

Comment: Guess the error message could include some hints regarding possible routing problems. [**It was changed recently**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/10760/files) to not show the wrong classname anymore, before that it would have told you that the class `Jobs_titleController` is missing.